# Paraview install fails

Tags: macos, cmake, paraview

I've managed to build Paraview 5.0 from source on OSX.

If I try to `make install` I get the following error:

> CMake Error at Qt/Components/cmake_install.cmake:380 (file):   file
>   INSTALL cannot find
>   "~/projects/ParaView-v5.0.0-source/build/Qt/Components/ui_pqExportStateWizard.h".
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):   VTK/cmake_install.cmake:223
>   (include)   cmake_install.cmake:59 (include)

I can't find the header file in the build directory.

Inside file `Paraview-source/Qt/Components/CMakeLists.txt` one can see:

```
if(PARAVIEW_INSTALL_DEVELOPMENT_FILES)   
    install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ui_pqExportStateWizard.h"
          DESTINATION "${VTK_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}") 
endif()
```

But the header is not installed.

I tried commenting out this section (`Qt/Components/cmake_install.cmake`)

```
if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "Unspecified")
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/paraview-5.0" TYPE FILE FILES "/Users/Leo/projects/ParaView-v5.0.0-source/build/Qt/Components/ui_pqExportStateWizard.h")
endif()
```

but after running `make install` it's overwritten.

How can I bypass or fix this?

Comment: If you want to eliminate some action, you need modify source file (`Paraview-source/Qt/Components/CMakeLists.txt`), not a generated one (Qt/Components/cmake_install.cmake).

Comment: Development installs aren't really working yet on OsX. Hence I'd suggest simply setting `PARAVIEW_INSTALL_DEVELOPMENT_FILES` to OFF in the CMake configuration step.